# Undefined method `name' in test, while working in development

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, integration-testing

I have a failing test while on the development server it works fine. The test generates the error:

```
ActionView::Template::Error: undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass
app/views/members/show.html.erb:15:in `_app_views_members_show_html_erb__387437852342830797_46300380'
test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:18:in `block in <class:SiteLayoutTest>'
```

The error refers to `.name` on the third line of the show view below. And it refers to `get member_path(@member_admin)` in the integration test.

I don't understand what could be causing this error. `name` is a column in the organization model but the relationship between organization and member (1:many) works fine. What is causeing this; why is Rails not recognizing `name` for the variable that it is?

In the members controller I have:

```
  def show
    @member = Member.find(params[:id])
    @organization = @member.organization
    redirect_to organization_path(@organization) and return unless (@member.activated || (current_member && !current_member.admin))
  end
```

In the show view:

```
<div class="col-md-5">
  <p><b>Fullname </b> <%= @member.fullname %></p>
  <p><b>Organization </b> <%= link_to @organization.name, organization_path(@organization) %></p>
  <p><b>Email</b> <%= @member.email %></p>
  <p><b>Phone</b> <%= @member.phone %></p>
</div>
```

The test:

```
  def setup
    @member_admin     = orgusers(:one)
  end

  test "layout links" do
    log_in_as("member", @member_admin)
    get member_path(@member_admin)
  end
```

Comment: Seems like  `@organization` does not exist.

Comment: It sounds like `member` might have no `organization` attached to it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simple, your `Member` doesn't have associated `Organization` in test. Make sure your test fixtures provide proper relationship between these models.

Comment: BTW, this actually leads to (introduced by) more serious problem: lack of proper model association. Member without association attached should raise an exception during consistency check stage, not here.

Comment: It's true, `organization` presence should be validated - and maybe it is - fixtures bypass validation.

Comment: Thanks, in the members fixtures I created the association through: `organization_id: 1`. Apparantly this didn't work and I had to refer to the organization fixture on basis of its name in the fixtures: `organization: companyA`.

Comment: Yes, the presence of organization is validated but apparently not within my fixtures (perhaps indeed a good idea to start the test by testing to see if the member indeed has an organization associated to it).